# Если пользуешься клиентом Source Tree, то нужно ли устанавливать дополнительно Git?

Tags: git

Я новичок в работе с системой версий и мне показалось что установка Git - это установка функционала с которым мы будем работать через разные Git клиенты, такие как SourceTree, например.

Но такое ощущение что клиенты сами по себе несут весь нужный функционал, вписанный в графический интерфейс, а Git - это ещё один клиент только без графического интерфейса.

Так Git - это всего лишь ещё один клиент для работы с гитом?

Comment: ну да, а Word это клиент для работы с вордом.

Comment: гит (а точнее, то, что устанавливается с сайта https://git-scm.com/downloads) - это необходимый и вполне достаточный минимум. Я обычно к этом добавляю хорошую дифф тулу, например, meld. А SourceTree - никому не нужная поделка, которая только вредит.

Comment: @KoVadim а мне было удобно) например откатить коммит или переписать текст коммита, посмотреть что было изменено в некоторых коммитах, история, поиск по ней с фильтрацией по пользователю или подстроке комментария. Удобная программка)

Comment: У sourcetree есть одна неприятная штука - он иногда содержит весьма странные баги. Например, показывает историю немного неправильно. Но этого хватает, что бы у людей волосы становились белые и пушистые.